# How can i import .DMP files into SQLiteStudio

Tags: mysql, workbench, sqlitestudio

i need to import some .DMP files into SQLiteStudio, i tried a lot of things but can´t find how to do it. If you can help me i appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You cannot import MySQL dump files into SQLite database. You need to first convert it into a format understandable by SQLite. There are several tools over the internet for doing so - just type "*convert mysql dump into sqlite*" in google or other search page. An example of such tool: https://github.com/dumblob/mysql2sqlite

Once you have the file compatible with SQLite, you can open SQLiteStudio, create an empty database and then right-click on it, pick "*Execute SQL from file*" and use the SQLite-compatible file you produced earlier.